# Change Sign-in ID to different email address

Tags: psn

My son's PSN Sign-in ID was set with his uncle's email address, but we can't access it and all of his information and data is on there. Is there any way we can change the Sign-in ID to my email address on his account?

Comment: This sounds like something you may need to contact PlayStation customer support about.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to call Sony support and ask them to change your Sign-in ID. They don't like to do it very much though, and they will ask you many questions to verify that it's actually you that's asking for the Sign-in ID change.

Call **1 (877) 865-7669** for Sony Support.

About a year and a half ago, I got locked out of my account, because my sign-in ID was a dead email and I forgot my password, and Sony Support changed it for me, so they should be able to do it for you.